# Що означає "у ржі на межі"?

Tags: значення-слів

Аналізуючи русальну пісню [У ржі на межі](http://ukrbooks.com/ua/U_rzhi_na_mezhi/), я не зрозуміла, що означає **"у ржі на межі"**:

> **У ржі на межі**, на кривій березі
>
> Там сиділа русалка.
>
> Просила русалка у дівочок сорочки.

У [Публічному електронному словнику української мови](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0) знайшла:

> **РЖА див. іржа́.**
>
> Словник української мови: в 11 тт. / АН УРСР. Інститут мовознавства; за ред. І. К. Білодіда. — К.: Наукова думка, 1970—1980. — Т. 7. — С. 526.
>
> **Ржа, ржі, ж. Ржавчина** (на желѣзѣ, водѣ). Їсть як ржи залізо. Ном. № 2726. Ржа вхполилась. Пристала ржавчина, начало ржавѣть. Черк. у.
>
> Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка. — К., 1907—1909. — Т. 4. — С. 14.

У [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/29/53382/12099.html) ще таке значення :

> **ІРЖА**
>
> II.
>   назва паразитичних грибів (з ряду іржастих), також хвороби, викликані ними; ознаки: рослини вкриті іржавими плямами, на уражених органах утворюються пустули, з яких при розтріскуванні висипається іржавий порошок - спори гриба; найшкідливіші: і. стеблова (зернових культур), і. бура пшениці, і. жовта зернових культур.

Але ні одне із цих значень не підходить для розуміння контексту русальної пісні.

Comment: Дякую ! Виправила помилку.

Comment: Прошу. + Пробіл, і буде ідеально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [Етимологічному словнику української мови](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom5.pdf), том 5 є такі статті:

> **ржа 1**, ржавець, ржавий, ржавина, ржавіти, ржавчеіна, ржеіна, ржія -див. іржа.
>
> **ржа 2**  - результат перенесення на грибкове захворювання злаків назви іржа "окислення заліза" на основі зовнішньої подібності. - Див. ще іржа.

Читаємо статтю про "іржа" (том 2, ст. 316):

> Іржа, **ржа**, [ржія] **«болото, де утворюється озерна жовта залізна руда».**

На сайті [Українська міфологія](http://proridne.net/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8.html) знаходимо, що:

> Русалки — водяні богині, які живуть на дні водоймищ.

Отже, найбільш ймовірно, що русалка, дім якої - водоймище, іноді виходить із свого "будинку", аби попрохати дівчат про послугу: "дати сорочку". Таким чином вона сідає на “криву березу”, яка знаходиться на земельній ділянці, що схожа на болото. Для уточнення місця сидіння вказано, що це межа.

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/mezha) читаємо:

> 2. Вузька цілинна смуга між полями, що є водночас і польовою стежкою або шляхом.
>
> Микола з товаришами мандрував з села, та не шляхом, а просто через поле межами (Нечуй-Левицький, II, 1956, 195).

Answer (score -2):

Ржа - це всього лиш жито. "У ржі на межі" означає: "на краю житнього поля". Пісня скоріш за все із центрально-східної (слобідської) України. Тож навіть прийменник "у" вжито в значенні "біля", так само, як в російській мові. Також "ржанной хлеб" (рос.) не є хлібом із цвіллю, а просто житній хліб.